# Nginx configuration with gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

Api is in Django framework and the Web app is in Angular both are different projects. Nginx and gunicorn worked well and upload both projects in the same directory but when I hit my domain it shows Django application default page. I want to show my static html page instead of Django default page.

```
'server{
         listen 443;
         server_name class.domain.com;

         root /var/www/html/;
         index index.html;

         location /static/ {
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
         }

         location ~ ^/ {
               include proxy_params;
               proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
         }
}'
```

Comment: I resolved the issue, below is the solution

Comment: location /api {
        rewrite ^/api(.*) $1 break;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;

    }

Comment: Hi @lucky ! If you solved the problem, mark the question as solved and try to answer your own question, not comment it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'server{
         listen 443;
         server_name class.domain.com;

         root /var/www/html/;
         index index.html;

         location /static/ {
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
         }

      location /api {
        rewrite ^/api(.*) $1 break;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;

    }
}'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).